# I made the best answer to my own question after posting a bounty on it. Now I'm losing $50$ points when I haven't done anything wrong. A bit unfair?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

The question I'm talking about: [For any unbounded set of real numbers, is there a subset which almost coincides with a uniformly spread out set of points an infinite amount of times?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297709/for-any-unbounded-set-of-real-numbers-is-there-a-subset-which-almost-coincides)

I answered it soon after I posted it, but after that I wasn't sure what to do about the bounty. But now I think I will lose the 50 points which seems a bit unfair. Why is the rule like this? What about another rule put in place so that members of the community can vote on whether or not a bounty can be refunded *if* the question-asker answers their own question better than other answers? What do you think?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13474/why-cant-you-get-awarded-the-bounty-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: I don't understand downvotes for my question. Even if the answer is, "no", that doesn't mean the question itself deserves downvotes... In my opinion, *any* genuinely asked question shouldn't be downvoted. And in my opinion, people who downvote questions should state their reason.

Comment: I did not down-vote this question, but on Meta (unlike Main!) down-votes do not indicate low quality of the question. Instead, they serve to indicate disagreement of down-voters with the premise of the question. The down-votes also do not result in loss of reputation on Meta. So, take it easy. :)

Comment: @MoisheKohan ah, ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. Not unfair.

If you put an ad in the paper, looking for a carpenter, say, to do some work. But then you decide to buckle down and do the thing yourself. Do you ask for a refund on your ad from the paper?

No. You paid for the exposure. What you did or didn't do afterwards is irrelevant.

Bounties are payments for higher foot traffic through a question. Because in the general case, more visibility means more people might see it means more people who could answer might see it and it is an incentive for these people to post an answer that is as good as they can make it. But you paid for the exposure. Not the answer.

If nothing else, it means that your answer is now receiving higher exposure and may garner even more upvotes than it would have otherwise. This is why when you bounty a question that you already answered, the minimum amount is higher than if you just bounty a random question. You're paying, in part, to get your answer exposed, and so you have something to gain.

Not to mention that these are, at the end of the day, made up internet points. But I guess it's easy for me to say that, having so many of them, but then again, that's my point... it's just internet points.

Comment: "it's just internet points." True, although there are also site privileges you get after you get a certain amount of points, so it's not only ego-stroking.

Comment: But I agree with the answer as a whole.

Comment: "True, although there are also site privileges you get after you get a certain amount of points," -- while not untrue, 50 points is really quite little in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: 100 upvotes and $4.65 will get you a free latte at Starbucks. ☺